# Recommended book for cocos2d?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, books

I'm an experienced programmer that recently got into iOS development by working through the big nerd ranch book by Aaron Hillegass and Joe Conway. I loved the way the book was structured in terms of typing in the code and doing the challenges.

I'm interested in learning more about iOS gaming and cocos2d, but am a complete newbie in terms of game development/design. There are [a number of books on amazon on cocos2d](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=cocos2d&x=0&y=0), can anyone recommend one in particular?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend this book :

http://apress.com/book/view/1430233036

check it out

Comment: any reason in particular you recommend this one? there are quite a few

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend wandering down to your local Large Chain Bookstore (Borders, Barnes & Noble, et cetera) and see if they have a copy of any of the books you are interested in. That way you can peruse them for yourself and hopefully get a better idea of whether or not a particular book would be good for you and your particular learning style. Amazon's "Look Inside" feature, if available for the books in question, may also allow you to do this to some extent.

Personally, I'd be very cautious about buying a book that focuses on a specific API, largely because such books tend to go out of date relatively quickly and thus I don't see them to be as strong of an investment. I would thus suggest that you take a good look at all the freely-available online reference and educational material for cocos2d and game development in general (if you have not already, of course) and see if that is suitable enough for you.

All of that having been said, I'm generally a fan of the O'Rielly books, however both of their iPhone books seem relatively old at this point. The Apress books have looked promising when I browsed them in stores, so that would be my secondary suggestion (the caveat being that I have not reviewed any of those books in detail and am basing this recommendation on my experience with the quality of the publisher's other material and quick flip-throughs of the books).

Answer (score 0):

There are only 2 books available on cocos2d, i think

https://www.packtpub.com/cocos2d-games-for-iphone-0-99-beginners-guide/book
http://apress.com/book/view/1430233036

from which i recommend the second one "Learn iPhone and iPad Cocos2D Game Development".
its very well written and a nice introduction to the topic. Autor has described very useful insights using his experience with tools and tips to make a iphone games.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen many books on Cocos2d, so I'm curious about the statement that there are "quite a few". Please share your list.

The book "Learn iPhone and iPad cocos2d Game Development" is available on Safari Books Online, if you happen to be a member, but I don't recommend it. As previously said, the book is easy to read and includes the author's best practices. On the downside, the writing style is perhaps too casual, the book is already dated with respect to the current version of cocos2d and it's I found it difficult to apply supplied code directly into my projects. I've been more successful using the tutorials on the Cocos2d website than with the book. The book also glosses over some topics, such as sound.

But since there are so few books on Cocos2d and there are at least two recommendations for this book, I suggest you try out the book in combination with tutorials on the product websites (Cocos2d, SneakyInput, etc), googling for specific information and of course asking questions here on Game Development - Stack Exchange. The book will give you a good idea on how things are supposed to work and you can use the web as a supplement.

Answer (score 0):

I would **highly** recommend you read Ray Wenderlich's excellent book on Cocos2d, "[Learning Cocos2D](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321735625)".  I've just finished reading it cover to cover, completely worth the price.  In particular, Rod and Ray introduce you to game concepts in a very gentle way through incremental level design.  They cover menus, level changes, sprites, sprite sheets, behaviors, AI, physics, etc.  In particular, the introduction to Box2D makes the book worthwhile, IMHO.

You can get a flavor of the book by reading some of the excellent tutorials and articles on Ray's site: http://www.raywenderlich.com/.

I'm a more experienced iOS developer, so reading the code samples was constructive (I didn't compile any of the example code, nor the final game "Space Viking").  I did enjoy that all the game code and assets are available for download, so you can build it yourself along the way.

Answer (score 0):

Direct links to useful presentations (especially for Tetrad moderator):

[intro to cocos2d](http://cocos2dbook.com/projects/360iDev2011-IntroToCocos2D.pdf)

[about performance](http://cocos2dbook.com/projects/Strougo_PerformanceTalk_Blog.pdf)

And my translation of the first presentation in Russian:

[intro to cocos2d на русском](https://dc2.safesync.com/NWtpFv/website/360iDev2011-IntroToCocos2D.pdf?a=8tPAe7QUHhg)